# Why is this XSLT variable returning undefined?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to write an XSLT function to select between some dates. I have parameters that are being converted to `xs:date` and then used to get the number of days between two of them, and format them appropriately. For some reason, the `termDate` variable is being reported as undefined, even though I can see in the Variables and Nodes/Values Set panels in Oxygen that the parameter references and element that does have a value.

```
<xsl:function name="my:getStatusDate">
    <xsl:param name="rehire"/>
    <xsl:param name="term"/>
    <xsl:param name="hire"/>

    <xsl:variable name="rehireDate" select="xs:date($rehire)" as="xs:date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="termDate" select="xs:date($term)" as="xs:date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="hireDate" select="xs:date($hire)" as="xs:date"/>        
    <xsl:variable name="dayDiffTermRehire" select="days-from-duration($termDate - $rehireDate)" as="xs:integer"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$term != '' and not($term)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$dayDiffTermRehire &gt; xs:integer(91)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date($rehireDate, '[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date($hireDate, '[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date($hireDate, '[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

The call site looks like this:

```
<ExpectedStatusEffectiveDate><xsl:value-of select="my:getStatusDate(RecentHireDate, TermDate, PreviousHireDate)"/></ExpectedStatusEffectiveDate>
```

A sample XML source looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Entry>
        <EmployeeFirstName>John</EmployeeFirstName>
        <EmployeeLastName>Doe</EmployeeLastName>
        <BirthDate>1940-01-01-01:00</BirthDate>
        <RecentHireDate>1970-05-20-07:00</RecentHireDate>
        <PreviousHireDate>1970-05-20-07:00</PreviousHireDate>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <EmployeeFirstName>Jane</EmployeeFirstName>
        <EmployeeLastName>Doe</EmployeeLastName>
        <BirthDate>1970-11-25-08:00</BirthDate>
        <RecentHireDate>2003-12-22-08:00</RecentHireDate>
        <PreviousHireDate>1970-06-19-07:00</PreviousHireDate>
        <TermDate>2000-01-13-08:00</TermDate> <!-- NOTE: this entry HAS a TermDate -->
    </Entry>
</Data>
```

Any idea why the termDate would be undefined in BOTH cases?

Comment: My test results were not correct. And so I was debugging in Oxygen and using the variable panes to see the current values.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in Oxygen. I was able to get it to work right. Not sure what the problem was. What's the protocol for something like this? Just delete the question?

Comment: What do you want to check with `<xsl:when test="$term != '' and not($term)">`? If you pass in an element like `<TermDate>2000-01-13-08:00</TermDate>` then `$term != ''` is true but `not($term)` is false. If you pass in an empty sequence (i.e. you don't have a `TermDate` element, then the first condition is false.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I bet that's related somehow. I'd removed it, and things seem to be working. Not really sure, but I think my tool was just bugged. That probably fixes my logic problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to chalk this up to an Oxygen bug. I'm not sure what changed, but after isolating the function into its own stylesheet, it started working. I then copied it back into the original, and everything seemed to work.